# calling static method from inside the class

Tags: python, static-methods

While calling static method from inside the class (which contains the static method), it can be done in following ways:

Class.method() or self.method()

What is the difference?

 
What are the unique use cases for each?

```
class TestStatic(object):
    @staticmethod
    def do_something():
        print 'I am static'

    def use_me(self):
        self.do_something() # 1st way
        TestStatic.do_something() # 2nd way

t = TestStatic()
t.use_me()
```

prints

```
I am static
I am static
```

Comment: Self is better. It works with inheritance, or if you rename the class.

Comment: For readability I prefer class.method.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By using `TestStatic.do_something()` you'd bypass any override on a subclass:

```
class SubclassStatic(TestStatic):
    @staticmethod
    def do_something():
        print 'I am the subclass'

s = SubclassStatic()
s.use_me()
```

will print

```
I am the subclass
I am static
```

This may be what you wanted, or maybe it wasn't. Pick the method that best fits your expectations.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `TestStatic.do_something()` is better because it demonstrates an understanding of static members. Static members are objects that belong to the class and methods that are called on the class, and in most cases, they are utility classes. Thus, calling the method via the class is more appropriate.